# Error while installing RabbitMQ Service on Windows

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to install RabbitMQ Service as a Windows Service. I see an option to install RabbitMQ Service from installer (v3.6.5). However, it does not work.

I write a Batch script trying to re-install RabbitMQ service **after running installer file.**

```
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\Users\%username%

call "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat" remove
call "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin\rabbitmq-service.bat" install

call net start RabbitMQ

call "C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.5\sbin\rabbitmq-plugins.bat" enable rabbitmq_management
```

However, this script is quite unstable.
Sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't.

I tested in many PCs with Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012.

When error occurs, it always occurs in **the last command** (enabling RabbitMQ management)

```
C:\Program Files\erl9.0\erts-9.0\bin\erlsrv: Service RabbitMQ removed from system.
C:\Program Files\erl9.0\erts-9.0\bin\erlsrv: Service RabbitMQ added to system.
The RabbitMQ service is starting.
The RabbitMQ service was started successfully.

Plugin configuration unchanged.

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@<myhost>... failed.
* Could not contact node rabbit@<myhost>.
Changes will take effect at broker restart.
* Options: --online  - fail if broker cannot be contacted.
--offline - do not try to contact broker.
```

Sometimes, I got this error

```
...
Plugin configuration unchanged.

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@<myhost>... failed.
Error: noproc
```

In my PC, I get the first error *(could not contact node...)* when **%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%** is **C:\users\myusername**. When I change to **C:\Windows**, it works well. Then I change back to **C:\users\**, it also works well,  no more error.

However, on a server with Windows Server 2012, even **C:\Windows** does not work *(could not contact node...).*

In all PCs, I see **.erlang.cookie** file in both **C:\Windows** and **C:\Users[username]**. (I don't know anything about erlang, just follow some instructions from other questions in StackOverFlow).

What is wrong with my script?

1. Is the error related to the version of RabbitMQ? I am not using the latest version.
2. Is it related to Erlang? I guess if Erlang caused this problem, then two commands about removing/installing RabbitMQ service would be failed.
3. Is it able to install the service without checking service option from installer, just run command **rabbitmq-service.bat install**?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the most recent version of the RabbitMQ installer for Windows, available [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html). I am assuming that `<myhost>` in your question is an edited-out hostname, not what is actually being used. You also don't mention which version of Erlang you have installed, but I assume it is a recent one.

You should uninstall RabbitMQ and ensure all traces are removed from `C:\Users\myusername` (be sure to check `%APPDATA%`) and `C:\Windows`. You should not have to change the default values of `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` prior to installation. Use an administrative account when running the Erlang and RabbitMQ `.exe` installers.

Please note that `3.6.12` has [this issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/1343) on Windows. A workaround is to set `vm_memory_calculation_strategy` to `erlang`. I fixed this issue and it will be delivered in `3.6.13`.

Thanks for using RabbitMQ!

Comment: With latest version of RabbitMQ, running both installers as admin, I get the same problem.
Without changing HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH, Erlang always tries to write cookie to P:/.erlang.cookie where P is not available. With this change, I still get the error "noproc" when trying to enable rabbitmq_management